# Manipulating a large array of audio samples in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, audio, signal-processing

I have an array of audio samples in C which I run algorithms on such as low-pass filters. I was thinking of converting my array to Objective-C before working on it. This is mainly because I am more comfortable with that language and it's conveniences (especially being able to get the length of the array easily and not having to deal with pointers).

I was wondering if there is any reason why this may be a bad idea. Or if there are any disadvantages to doing this that I'm not aware of. Like maybe speed in processing such a large amount of samples (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard practice is to use a c style array for manipulating an array of audio.  This is because if you have to use an Objective-c container object with obj-c messaging to access each element, the performance will be bad, and as you note, the number of samples with audio can be quite large.

This is especially true for real time processing such as processing audio samples that live in the system audio io callback, which have to do the job within a certain number of milliseconds or the sound will cut out.

What you could do is define a struct (or even an objective c class) that has the audio buffer array as well as info elements like size, number of channels, etc, to wrap it together for you in one location.  That way when you access the buffer, you don't need to get into obj-c efficiency issues, and you still have the buffer specification info available.

Here's an example:

```
typedef struct filter_buffer {
   uint16_t* buffer;
   int   channels;
   int   num_frames;
} filter_buffer;
```

You then just need a call that initializes it.

You could do something with objective-c like:

```
@interface FilterBuffer : NSObject
{
  uint16_t* buffer;
  int   channels;
  int   num_frames;   
}

-initWithBuffer:(unit16_t*)buf channels:(int)c numFrames:(int)n;
...//accessors etc
@end

@implementation FilterBuffer
-initWithBuffer:(unit16_t*)buf channels:(int)c numFrames:(int)n
{
   if ((self = [super init)) {
      buffer = buf;
      channels = c;
      num_frames = n;
   }
   return self;
}
...
@end
}
```

Comment: It's not real time though. Do you think this would still be a problem?

Comment: It would work, just be noticeably slower.  I would consider defining an obj-c wrapper around the c buffer instead of using something like an NSMutableArray to keep track of each sample though.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a snippet of code as to what that would look like. I'm a bit of a noob :).

Comment: Also, I found this concerning CFArrays. Maybe this is the answer that I'm looking for? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I posted an example that uses normal arrays (buffers).  You are looking at dynamic arrays there.  If it is just prototyping a non-realtime processing code and you really feel much more comfortable with NSMutableArray I would use that over the CF counterparts.  You can always change things later.

Comment: Okay, this seems really good. So basically I don't even need to use a C struct. I can use Objective-C and stick my audio samples in a uint16_t array. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: yeah, make sure that your underlying samples are uint16_t though, and just change it if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantages would be:

- Speed. It will be significantly slower.
- It's not usable for realtime, objc messaging is significantly slower and it may lock.
- It's not portable.
- It's won't integrate well with other libraries.
- Depending on how you approach this, it could have a *huge* memory impact. Using an array of `NSNumbers` (for example) would require several *times* the memory. In fact, that's what your post implies -- an `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumber`s.
- You won't learn to read or write audio programs properly. The programs you see in the real world are typically in C++ and C.
- A C array is **not** a scary thing =)
- You'll probably just end up rewriting it when you need to reuse it because it's the wrong tool for the job in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

DSP using Objective C objects in inner loops is bad for performance reasons.  For this reason, among others, you will find most audio filter and DSP algorithms published in plain C, perhaps C++, or similar pseudo-code.  So you may have to get used to reading plain C DSP code anyway.

Also, C is a proper subset of Objective C.